# Essentials for life in the modern era

Tags: travel, modern

What would someone in a modern city need for life? They do not have a house, and live in a place with only a bedroom and bathroom, like a dorm room style thing. They are limited to one carry on suitcase, and one large satchel.  I am looking for the absolute essentials they must have, with few luxuries.

---

**Needs**

1. **Clothing** ( compact for many climates, would appreciate ideas for both men and women..)
2. **Toiletries** (Soap, toothpaste, washcloth, etc. Is here anything that is absolutely necessary, anything you could do without?)
3. **Some** form of earning money** (Art, instrument, plain tools, anything that would be easy to transport)
4. **Others** miscellaneous useful items** ( electronics, duct tape, rubber bands, compass, etc.)

Comment: You should look into nomadic tribes and communities. There have been many throughout Asia and Africa in both history and the modern day, and they should be able to answer most of the questions about nomadic lifestyles you need for your story.

Comment: @Bewilderer no they don’t. I am looking for someone who is more international, across the globe, and at a higher tech level. More someone trying to avoid capture than nomadic by nature.

Comment: Having done a walking holiday over long distance (>1000 km) I can tell you that what you carry strongly depends on what climate and conditions you expect. You don't carry winter gear if you are moving in summer, it's just a waste of energies.

Comment: If someone is avoiding capture, they aren't taking much with them. Literally everything else comes secondary to avoiding capture. That includes earning money, paying for things, and even health care. Especially seen as theft in this situation is likely preferable to capture, and provides benefits in increasing the difficulty of being detected.

Comment: This has similar problems to your previous question.  There's one heck of a difference between traveling between e.g. cities and towns by rail and wandering forests in summer and wandering in winter.  Even in towns and cities winter and summer could vary between deadly in short periods of exposure at both ends of the scale.  There's the significant problem of ID, passport, cross borders and being stopped by police.  Male and female need different things.  The variations are simply too broad.

Comment: How to hide : establish an identity, find somewhere quiet to live as that identity and do so quietly and lawfully (very lawfully).  Have a backup identity and safe house if you have to go on the run.  Don't travel, especially across borders.  Don't get your name in the paper, or become prominent in anything, even the local football team or darts club.  Low profile.

Comment: This question is what we call "[too story-based](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300)."  The contents of that luggage is 100% dependent on the plot (circumstances) of your story, not the rules (systems) of your world.  Yes, we could recommend common items like a knife, fork, cup, extra socks, etc., but no detail is in any way relevant unless it's relevant to your story, which is off-topic here.

Comment: @JBH if you call the question too story-based I recommend you go back and reread the criteria for what constitutes too story-based. What a person carries while continually travelling is about their capacities & capabilities is an element of that world and how someone in that world would accomplish that, even if it is in the modern world.

Comment: How has the edit changed the nature of the question?  All you did was change the circumstances (the essence of being story-based).

Comment: I am asking about the world as a whole, and this is an awnserable question. In the modern world, what items do you need for life?

Comment: After the edit, I think that it is less story-oriented, but still not much **world**building. And really opinion-based. A suit case full of cash and a clean pair of socks would work wonder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple put, there is going to be no Universal set of equipment that you can take that will be suitable for all conditions. So lets start with the core basics.

**Money**

Why Money first? Money is your bread and butter. If your in a cold place, money lets you get warm clothes. If you in a tropical environment, Money can get you a singlet, some deo, a hat. If you need a place to stay you need money. If your in a city and need food, you need money. So making money is going to be the first thing you need. The easiest way I see this is via Busking. All you need is an instrument and something to hold the money. Now this is going to be up to you, since your going to have stricter requirements, but instruments like a: Guitar, Harmonica, Bucket and Drumstick, Violin, Banjo, drum sticks and glass bottles, Keyboard, flute, clarinet, recorder are all valid ways which only require an instrument. You can also sing, but often singers need a microphone and speakers due to the ambient noise. If our willing to, you can also perform. Good dancers, paintings, Mimes, poetry are also valid options, but often seem much harder to generate that sweet cash flow. Along with that you need something to hold the money. For an instrument, the case it comes in is usually a good choice, but you can also use a Hat, Handkerchief, towel.

**Toiletries**

This is pretty standard. You just need a towel and a toothbrush. Everything else is extra and you can buy it with the money you have on the way, or do without. While it might be uncomfortable not having other stuff like toothpaste, I don't see why you could consider it a core resource, especially when its a consumable resource. Same with soap. The basic stuff you need is water, towel and toothbrush. Everything else you buy if you have the money, or go without. If you really want it, then you would need, a Towel, toothbrush, toothpaste, something to scrub your body with, shampoo, soap, nail clippers, floss, moisturizer, brush, hair dryer, clear cleaner, scissors for your hair, etc.

**Clothing**

Universal clothing is going to be hard. You want some sturdy shoes. I would suggest leather and very protective like steel cap work boots because you can wear it anywhere and step on almost anything with those and be safe. On the sand, in the water (You might down), over glass, stone, metal. Completely enclosed shoes are going to be a must. As for clothes, you could potentially get away with shorts, shirt and a very thick jacket. Of course, you will likely want to trade, sell and buy clothes as you go using that sweet money you made by busking. In a humid environment, sell the jacket and buy some singlets. In a cold environment, sell the singlets so some pervert and buy a jacket. Supplement any missing money by earning more money. Weather conditions change gradually, so your not going to be sweating one day and freezing the next.

**Others?**

This is very broad and will generally depend on what you are going out for. A compass is useless if you don't have a map to use it with, and maps are going to vary in detail and from region to region. In fact, maps now are basically an artifact in modern society, so you would literally be better off with a phone and dropping by into libraries and starbucks to charge it. Carry 1 -2 extra batteries and your good to go. Other than that, I would suggest rope, because you never know when that is useful, thermal sheets for protection, sunscreen (skin cancer is no joke), a hat (with the corks to keep flies out), a utility knife, ID/Passport ( so you don't get arrested), GPS beacon (so your loved ones and family can find you), a journal (so when you inevitably die and someone finds your remains, they can make a movie out of our adventure), a pen (to write with).

**Summary**

- Phone With extra batteries and gps capabilities
- Steel cap boots
- an Instrument of some sort
- A hat
- Steel cap shoes
- Tooth brush
- Towel
- Utility Knife/tool
- Passport
- Shorts
- Tshirt
- Super thick insulated coat (For the cold)
- Thick socks over your ankles ( it is a serious pain to wear steel caps with no ankle protection )
- As many credit cards as you can fit into the remaining space (probably the most important one)

Answer (score -2):

- In the real world, they should remember **keeping up appearances**. Police and border officials really do not like penniless vagrants. Even if their wandering is legal and they are let through, there are suspicions. What they do accept are backpacking tourists.

  - Carry a couple of [Lonely Planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lonely_Planet) books, with the right one at the top of the backpack or sticking out of a pocket.
  - A rolled sleeping pad tied to the pack, a lightweight refillable water bottle, etc.
- In a different vein, some parts of Europe still respect the [Journeyman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journeyman_years) tradition for craftsmen, notably carpentry and roofing. That would require the wanderer to be a craftsman, of course.

Answer (score -2):

Have some worn but clean clothes for begging along with your normal clothes.

In Britain at least, one actual tactic of homeless people is to use psychology and beg selectively.

When you are hungry, sit outside McDonald's and ask for money.

Influenced by reverse psychology, some people will offer to buy you an item of food instead. When you have eaten enough, move to near a cash machine and ask for money for a meal. This reassures them that they are not funding your drug or alcohol habit and they may well give you some money.

Your good quality clothes can be hidden in your sleeping bag that you use to sit on.